# i want to convert day number to day name

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kusto-explorer

i want to get a date and day name in one column for which i have made dynamic date but i am unable to create day name from day number and mix both date and day name in one column. please help.

```
T 
| where name has "Samplelog"
| extend Eventdate = strcat(datetime_part("day",timestamp))
| extend day_strg = tostring(Eventdate)
| extend day_Alp = dynamic({"0":"Sun", "1":"Mon", "2":"Tue", "3": "Wed", "4": "Thu", "5":"Fri", "6": "Sat"})
| extend day_num = dayofweek(timestamp) / 1d
| extend months = dynamic({"1":"Jan", "2":"Feb", "3":"Mar", "4":"Apr","5":"May","6":"Jun","7":"Jul","8":"Aug","9":"Sep","10":"Oct","11":"Nov","12":"Dec"})
| extend Eventdate = strcat(datetime_part("day",timestamp),"-",months[tostring(getmonth(timestamp))], "-", getyear(timestamp))
| extend Week_Num = case(day_strg in (range(1, 7, 1)), "1", day_strg in (range(8, 14, 1)), "2",day_strg in (range(15, 21, 1)), "3",day_strg in (range(22, 31, 1)), "4", "0")
| extend weekend = iff(Week_Num in (2,4) and day_num == 6 or day_num == 0, "weekend", "working day")
//| summarize Count=count() by bin(timestamp,1d)
```

Comment: "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let prm_day_of_week = dynamic(["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]);
let prm_month = dynamic(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]);
let mydata = materialize (range i from 1 to 10 step 1 | extend dttm = ago(rand()*1d*365));
mydata
| extend dayofweek = dayofweek(dttm), monthofyear = monthofyear(dttm)
| extend dayofweek_name = prm_day_of_week[toint(dayofweek/1d)], monthofyear_name = prm_month[monthofyear-1]
```

| i | dttm | dayofweek | monthofyear | dayofweek_name | monthofyear_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-04-11T17:03:13.0661553Z | 00:00:00 | 4 | Sun | Apr |
| 6 | 2021-05-31T20:39:37.7726143Z | 1.00:00:00 | 5 | Mon | May |
| 1 | 2021-06-21T19:11:27.7126358Z | 1.00:00:00 | 6 | Mon | Jun |
| 10 | 2021-06-23T00:28:09.1442068Z | 3.00:00:00 | 6 | Wed | Jun |
| 7 | 2021-06-25T22:32:22.4456643Z | 5.00:00:00 | 6 | Fri | Jun |
| 4 | 2021-08-05T02:47:06.9960523Z | 4.00:00:00 | 8 | Thu | Aug |
| 5 | 2021-09-24T10:09:35.0279053Z | 5.00:00:00 | 9 | Fri | Sep |
| 8 | 2022-02-06T08:55:36.8755718Z | 00:00:00 | 2 | Sun | Feb |
| 2 | 2022-02-28T07:11:29.5729928Z | 1.00:00:00 | 2 | Mon | Feb |
| 9 | 2022-03-02T00:26:16.2603593Z | 3.00:00:00 | 3 | Wed | Mar |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22RTUvEMBCG7wv7H4ae2mVFi%20hFPAiyh4J6WMFDKWVspt1gk5Q4VSv%20eDupa3fF05NJ3jyTj5YYOm9KhUPp6vKd6AWuQQ0Wja7iPNr2NlpDdOcCHnsSPJEK1a4XbLwWbJGjIrlaLtofpXGWd0eyDINlQ8/BiV5w0/mpGgTZ1C/r27DWN0FNneChYsG9exPcUjX3M4NCxrGZQSavsdWfBLFH2xBoqL0zkAI7SM/glakbiy%20gDyarQDGbcSM2TvIqTlapWp1fXiTinrzLxZzGwdX7V9qPY3Ekawg3dvVA6OUoczUF/tOU49vQGP7zBzk7bTn%20jZ2mKimOGhxuDNP5weJJWnwD00CRRdkBAAA=)

Comment: thank you, it works. you are champion sir,